# The following Makefile is not working and I am not sure what's going on

Tags: makefile

```
obj-m += task.o
all:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Makefile:3: *** missing separator.  Stop.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have the real tab character in front of the entry, e.g.

```
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

It has to be \t, the Tab character, not merely spaces.

To verify, you can run `cat -T Makefile`:

```
$ cat -T Makefile 
all:
^Iecho "foo"
foo:
^Iecho "bar"
```

`^I` indicates a tab character. Verify that **all** lines succeeding a target is tab-indented.